# When users update the Android application on device the shared preference containing data regarding login got erased so required to login again?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, storage, autologin

When I tried searching that every post saying `SharedPreferences` not got erased but in my case they got erased and even this problem varies from device to device.

Comment: All most all devices clearing shared preferences but on some devices we see they don't required to login again like on motox and motog

Comment: usually shared preferences will not deleted. Do You have any function to erease shared preferences in Your code?

Comment: Yes there is one fuction but there is no call to this function                   public static boolean clearSession(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(KEYSESSION, 0);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        return editor.commit();
    }

Comment: Any help for this post?